# how to use n model in one root in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

hi i have one root like this code

```
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<button >Platform</button>
<button >Game</button>
<button >Score</button>
<hr />

<div id="root"></div>
```

index.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

app.js code

```
    import React ,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Modal,ModalHeader,ModalBody,ModalFooter,FormGroup,Label,Input,Table ,Button} from 'reactstrap';


class App extends Component{
  state={
    books:[],
    NewBookData:{
      Title:'',
      Rating:''
    },
    EditBookData:{
      Id:'',
      Title:'',
      Rating:''
    },

    NewBookModal:false,
    EditBookModal:false
  }
....
```

this root is ok for default jobs,but i want ovveride this root base on platform ,game , ...
how i can this work?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'root'? The body with buttons??

Comment: root is div,game,platform , ... is model and i want click on game change div to crud game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use Route like this code

1.create 3 js file for Platform,game,score,... in Component Folder like this code

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
class Game extends Component {
    render(){
    return (
     <h1>this is game page</h1> 
    );
    }
  }
  export default Game;
```

2.import this code to app.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';
import gamePage from './Component/game';
import platformPage from './Component/platform';
import scorePage from './Component/score';
```

3.use Route to send to models

```
  <Router>
<div className="App">
  <ul>
    <li>
  <NavLink to="/platform" exact activeStyle={{color:'violet'}}>Platform</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
  <NavLink to="/game" exact activeStyle={{color:'violet'}}>Game</NavLink>
  </li>
  <li>
  <NavLink to="/score" exact activeStyle={{color:'violet'}}>Score</NavLink>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <Route path="/platform" exact strict component={platformPage}/>

  <Route path="/game" exact strict component={gamePage}/>

  <Route path="/score" exact strict component={scorePage}  /> 

</div>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make an outter react component which contains the buttons and all nested components for 'Platform', 'Game', 'Score'. You should recomponentize your app and not 'override'.